# ProgrammingError: LOB variable no longer valid after subsequent fetch

Tags: python, sql, oracle, pandas, cx-oracle

[Error when selecting a column ps_retourintervention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJYLQ.png)

This error shows when I'm trying to select the column `ps_retourintervention` and put it in a pandas dataframe .

This code works when selecting other columns from the same table in the database.

This query works also when I execute it in SQL developer here is it's result.

[image: Result of the query in SQL developer]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a limitation of versions of cx_Oracle 5 and earlier. The new version (cx_Oracle 6) doesn't have this limitation. You can upgrade using this command:

```
python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, 
i will try to pass a ticket to upgrade it, because i work in a cloud server, it will take time. 

Can you explain why it is not working ? i mean the reason why only is column.

Comment: In cx_Oracle 5 and earlier the LOB locators were stored in the array used for fetching; so each round trip to the database would overwrite the LOB locators from the previous fetch. In cx_Oracle 6, the LOB locators are associated with the LOBs themselves.

Answer (score 4):

For those who can not update, follwo this link,
http://kamushin.github.io/learning/python_oracle.html

Iterate the cursor object and convert LOB object to str.

Comment: The link is helpful, wish you've included the answer here.